# How to properly type filter operator in rxjs 6 angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to use filter (rxjs6). I stumbled on a typescript error :
[image]
    Argument type (value:any, index:any)=>boolean is not assignable to parameter type (value:T, index:number)=>boolean

It is working well in dev mode. But I cant

> ng build

And if I try

```
const filter1 = filter((value: { contract: string, language: string }, index: number) => value.contract !== null && value.language !== null);
```

I got

```
   Argument of type (value:{contract: string, language: string}, index:number)=>boolean is not assignable to parameter type (value:{contract: string, language: string}, index:number)=>boolean
```

Comment: make sure you use the correct import
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: I do : import { debounceTime, filter, mergeMap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: Could you try `filter<any>(`

Comment: already tried... same same

Comment: @Stefdelec Can you make a stackblitz demo?

Comment: The problem is, it is a typescript error not a angular/rxjs

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-fqsfbf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Stefdelec I don't see any error in the demo you posted

Comment: Yes, because it is a typescript error!

Comment: How do you handle generic type with filter?

Comment: since the entire code is not visible, why define a second argument `index`, if you don't plan to use it (as per your screenshot attachment)?

Comment: I tried every case with or without index. Same same.

Comment: @Stefdelec stackblitz shows TypeScript errors as well.

Comment: That error is bizarre.  @Stefdelec, if you are still stuck, please publish a repository that reproduces the problem for you and I will look.

Comment: I got the same error, I fixed by using `first(val => val !== null/undefined)` instead, for me it's fine to kill the observable, very weird!

Comment: ah I was importing filter from:  `import { filter } from 'minimatch';`